# Algorithm that deletes parts of a certain string given a certain condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was recently struggling to create the algorithm I describe in the title. my latest and in my opinion best attempt to get the results is the following:

```
   function outPut (intake){
  messagePrefab = `\n<:normal:624712757496905729>: x${normal}\n<:fire:624712757329264650>: x${fire} \n<:water:624712756834336788>: x${water}\n<:electr:624712757974925313>: x${electr} \n<:grass:624712758973169685>: x${grass} \n<:ice:624712757006172174>: x${ice} \n<:fight:624712757928919061>: x${fight} \n<:poison:624712758885220382>: x${poison} \n<:ground:624712758314926084>: x${ground} \n<:flying:624712757391917058>: x${flying} \n<:psychc:624712758520446992>: x${psychc} \n<:bug:624712756582547456>: x${bug} \n<:rock:624712758847602698>: x${rock} \n<:ghost:624712756699856907>: x${ghost} \n<:dragon:624712756821622786>: x${dragon} \n<:dark:624688707135471624>: x${dark} \n<:steel:624712757555625985>: x${steel} \n<:fairy:624712758641950721>: x${fairy}`  

  var a = messagePrefab.split("\n");
  a.forEach(
    (out) => {
       if(out.endsWith("x1")){
        temp1 = a.indexOf(out);
        a.splice(temp1, 1);
      } 
      console.log(out);
    }
  )
message.reply(a);
return;
}
```

so as you can guess I got a lot more algorithms that just changes the values of some variables inside the string. The string is showing me the values alright but I get complains that the string is showing unnecessary values. Those unnecessary values being if a variable equals "1". To get it simpler, if variable inside the string has the value "1" then it is not needed in the string neither the custom emote behind it.

My algorithm is supposed to split the message into an array and checks if one by one any element of the array ends with x1 if it sees it, it deletes it, well that's in theory but for some reason the output of the string comes out unchanged.

Comment: If your issue is with superfluous values, you should refine your filter condition (ie check if the value is one as well). I would suggest you look into the Array.filter() method.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally bad practice to modify an array while you're iterating over it with a higher-order function; that can lead to unexpected results. I would suggest just using `Array.filter` anyway; it's easier. It also seems like `message.reply` would take a string, not an array?:

```
function outPut(intake){
  messagePrefab = `\n<:normal:624712757496905729>: x${normal}\n<:fire:624712757329264650>: x${fire} \n<:water:624712756834336788>: x${water}\n<:electr:624712757974925313>: x${electr} \n<:grass:624712758973169685>: x${grass} \n<:ice:624712757006172174>: x${ice} \n<:fight:624712757928919061>: x${fight} \n<:poison:624712758885220382>: x${poison} \n<:ground:624712758314926084>: x${ground} \n<:flying:624712757391917058>: x${flying} \n<:psychc:624712758520446992>: x${psychc} \n<:bug:624712756582547456>: x${bug} \n<:rock:624712758847602698>: x${rock} \n<:ghost:624712756699856907>: x${ghost} \n<:dragon:624712756821622786>: x${dragon} \n<:dark:624688707135471624>: x${dark} \n<:steel:624712757555625985>: x${steel} \n<:fairy:624712758641950721>: x${fairy}`;

  var a = messagePrefab.split("\n");
  a = a.filter(out => !out.endsWith("x1"));
  message.reply(a.join("\n"));
}
```

You could also do the same filtering with a simple regex:

```
function outPut(intake){
  messagePrefab = `\n<:normal:624712757496905729>: x${normal}\n<:fire:624712757329264650>: x${fire} \n<:water:624712756834336788>: x${water}\n<:electr:624712757974925313>: x${electr} \n<:grass:624712758973169685>: x${grass} \n<:ice:624712757006172174>: x${ice} \n<:fight:624712757928919061>: x${fight} \n<:poison:624712758885220382>: x${poison} \n<:ground:624712758314926084>: x${ground} \n<:flying:624712757391917058>: x${flying} \n<:psychc:624712758520446992>: x${psychc} \n<:bug:624712756582547456>: x${bug} \n<:rock:624712758847602698>: x${rock} \n<:ghost:624712756699856907>: x${ghost} \n<:dragon:624712756821622786>: x${dragon} \n<:dark:624688707135471624>: x${dark} \n<:steel:624712757555625985>: x${steel} \n<:fairy:624712758641950721>: x${fairy}`;
  message.reply(messagePrefab.replace(/\n.*?x1(?:\n|$)/ig, '\n'));
}
```

Comment: with regex you are replacing two `\n`s, also last one does not ends with `\n`

Comment: @AZ_ True; fixed :)

Comment: As I can see on documentation message.reply can take both string or an array, although I use it as a string. I tried both your options although it seems the first one does not give any sign of working. The second one though has some peculiar effect. Now I have to do some explaining. The algorithm before Output() is supposed to pass the values on the same function once or twice, when it passes once the commands you send me deletes the first \n of the string, if the algorithm pass from it twice, it deletes the first and the second \n of the string.

Comment: Oh I see two more comments were added with a fix for the second one, I will try it

Comment: Well... none of them have any effect to the output now, it just outputs everything like always :/

Comment: if you can show me a more efficient way for my bot to reply those values in a way that I can edit them in and out , I'd not have a problem to do any modifications to the string, it is just a normal algorithm that changes the value of some variables after all.

Comment: Notice that some of your lines end in `x#\n` and some end in `x# \n` -- that space matters. They need to be consistent if you're only checking for one of them.

Comment: i got rid of the disparities of the string, i've taken care of every single space it had. Now something strange happens, it deletes many of the things that were x1 and leaves many of them untouched.